# can't SideNavigationController in my other view controllers

Tags: cosmicmind

https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material

in its samples SideNavigationController is just used as root view controller (app delegate ) 
what should I do if I want to use it in my other view controllers not just as my first app page

Answer (score 0):

The `SideNavigationController` persists across all UIViewControllers, if you place in the `rootViewController` another type of navigation controller, like `MenuController`, `BottomNavigationController`, and `NavigationController`. There is also a method you can use called `transitionFromRootViewController` which allows you to switch the `rootViewController` of the `SideNavigationController`. In the example project [App](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/tree/master/Examples/Programmatic/App) you can see this being done.